# different colors on elements in listview

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin

Is it possible to change the color to a given textcell og viewcell in xaml?

In my case I want to change the color to a given element based upon a given value.
I tried to use backgroundcolor in the viewcell, but this affect all the elements.

Is there any way to affect only one given cell?

This is my xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="postListView" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Green">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: you can bind the BGColor to a value in your data, and use a ValueConverter to convert the data value into an appropriate color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take a look to this repo

[Binding with listview](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestBindingWithListView)

In the ViewCell I have a StackLayout with a Binding

```
slView.SetBinding(StackLayout.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor");
```

In MyModel I have a string

```
public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

Then, in ViewModel, I set the color

```
List.Add(new Model { Description = "D1", Cost = 10.0, Qty = 1, BackgroundColor = "#9ac16e", TextColor = "#001833" });
```